# displaying form and title on same line

Tags: php, html, css, flexbox, less

I feel like Ive tried all the stack overflow solutions but none of them seem to work.
I am trying to get the title and form to be on the same row. This is what it looks like right now. [image]

This is what my HTML looks like

```
{% block blockbody %}
    <div class="mark">
        <div class="mark__svg">
            {% include '_svg/mark-gray.svg' %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bound bound--layout">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <h1 class="block__title">{{ (block.title ?: post.title)|raw }}</h1>
                {{ filter_form }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block masthead %}
    {% set filter_form %}
        <form method="get" class= "filters" action="{{ post.link }}">
            <select name="practice-area" id="practice-area">
                {% for option in wp.get({post_type:'practice',orderby:'title',order:'ASC',posts_per_page:-1}) %}
                    {% set option = TimberPost(option) %}
                    
                    <option value="">Filter by Practice Area</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </form>
    {% endset %}
    {% include '4_blocks/masthead-simple.twig' with {block: post.meta('masthead')[0], class:' block--masthead-tall'} %} 
{% endblock %}
```

This is what my css looks like

```
.block--masthead-simple {

    .content {
        .flexWidth(100%);
        align-self: flex-end;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .block__title {
        .headline;
        line-height: 1.354;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    select#practice-area {
        float: right;
        display: flex;
        padding: 0 45px 0 15px;
        color:#333;
        height: 55px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: 20px;
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

Ive tried

```
flex-direction: row;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline;
```

Comment: Please post the generated output/html this is not a twig related question

Comment: I was able to solve this by just adding margin-bottom: -100px;

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex;` is not working for you because it needs to be applied to the element that contains the page title and the form. So I've taken your HTML above, removed template tags from it, and added a `<div>` that contains both the title and the form. I've also commented out the SVG part as it's not clear where the SVG is supposed to be.

```css
.content {
        align-self: flex-end;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .block__title {
        line-height: 1.354;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    select#practice-area {
        float: right;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding: 0 45px 0 15px;
        color:#333;
        height: 55px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: 20px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- <div class="mark">
        <div class="mark__svg">
            {% include '_svg/mark-gray.svg' %}
        </div>
    </div> -->
    <div class="bound bound--layout">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <h1 class="block__title">{{ (block.title ?: post.title)|raw }}</h1>
                {{ filter_form }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <form method="get" class= "filters" action="{{ post.link }}">
            <select name="practice-area" id="practice-area">
                    
                    <option value="">Filter by Practice Area</option>
            </select>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Im not using display: inline. Its just what Ive tried. I have display:flex as my original code.

Comment: I updated code above with a couple of more fixes

Comment: this solution only gets the form to sit right on top of the title on the left

Comment: is there a margin/padding over the heading text? add `margin-top: 0;` and `padding-top: 0;` to the heading text and try again.

Comment: remove `align-self: flex-end;` from your CSS as well. It's not clear to which element it gets applied as the HTML you've posted seems to not be complete, but it's worth a try as well..

Comment: ive added and removed everything youve said. None of it seems to work. Ive also added the missing html

Comment: The problem was that `display: flex;` was applied to the wrong element. Now that you've updated the HTML it became clear. I've added a code snippet above, try to modify your code similarly and it should work..